# How powerful is Guest blogging for SEO?

Tags: seo, backlinks, guest-blogging

**With respect to all the senior members**, 
I am a newbie & I make 50 backlinks for my site every day, (using forum, social bookmarking and Blog commenting) recently my experienced cousin said that Google doesn't value these type of link anymore like they once used to. They love backlinks which are valuable and natural & suggested me to build natural link via Guest Blogging and Broken link building methods, because instead of making those forum & other links(50), I should make 5 natural links a day which will help me rank better.

My question is, is it true? are natural links really powerful than the other ones?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, natural backlink approach will return in sustainable ranking for long period of time.

Gest Post: You need to be mindful of this too.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en

A big NO to cheap and poor linking approach like blog commenting, spam links from forum etc. 50 a day is way too high. This approach will lead to a penalty from Google.

The best option is, you should work on building rich content and better user experience and strategy towards natural backlink.

Answer (score 1):

The process you're describing was out of date 10 years ago, and your cousins isn't much better. I doubt Google is counting your links at all (they are all probably nofollow). Guest blogging  for links is also a well-known spam technique, and any blog that allows it runs the risk of being penalised.

This is not how to do SEO. Look at the technical aspects of SEO and ensure your site is able to be easily crawled and understood by Google. Research your subject category and identify popular trends and keywords. Make useful relevant content that answers questions.

The approach you had was spammy 10 years ago, and is of no use.

Comment: I liked this answer soooooo much I was not sure to up vote or ask it to marry me! Cheers!!